# Fixed position Div ALWAYS appear on top?

Tags: css, html

I Have a fixed position  tag that is styled as follows within my CSS:

```
#facebook {
height: 249px;
width: 50px;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 200px;
}
```

There is a flash (.swf) header image on my website, and when the resolution of the browser is low enough, the facebook div is partially hidden by the flash header.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <body id="index">
 <div id="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="50" height="249" border="0"      usemap="#Map" />
 <map name="Map" id="Map">
 <area shape="rect" coords="2,154,40,191" href="http://www.youtube.com/" />
 <area shape="rect" coords="3,202,39,240" href="http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=72781675198" />
 </map>
 </div>
 <div id="wrapper">
 …
   <div id="title_box"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    data="images/flash.swf" 
    width="960" height="450">
 <param name="movie" value="images/flash.swf" />
 <img src="images/header.jpg" />
 </object></div>
```

How do I get it so my facebook fixed position div is always displayed on top of this .swf content?

Thanks in advance

Jon

Comment: perhaps, adding z-index can do

Comment: JUST THOUGHT I SHOULD ADD: Where it obstructs initially is a .swf header, is this relevant?

As I just tested and this .swf header is the only thing that goes over the top of the tab, the tab is then shown if u scroll past the header.

www.tomfrostpersonaltrainer.co.uk is the website to see a working example of my problem (use chrome and resize the window)

It's just a site I made for a friend of mine.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please experimentX or provide an example? is z-index a css attribute?

Comment: @JonKyte i would suggest @RobertKoritnik first of all, and then if not then @diEcho with same CSS expect for `position: absolute;`

Comment: @Jon: You should edit your question to provide **very relevant** info that Flash is rendered over your `div`. That's **very important.** Even if you got your answer you were looking for it's still important to edit it for future reference when someone else may have exact same problem.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Ok I will clean it up a bit, thank's for the head's up, and your input to helping me find my answer.

Comment: @Jon: No worries. Always glad to help within reason. :) and a +1 from me because you will clean it up (making it very useful)

Comment: Thank you, it's all cleaned up now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the content is obstructed by flash, even with a correct z-index, add `wmode="transparent"` to the flash embed script.

Comment: Hi thank you VirusZ, I tried adjusting the z-index and also the positioning to absolute and neither worked (i'm sure they we're correct, just did not work due to this specific matter being obstructed by flash).

Any way, adding the transparency to the flash embed script sorted my problem. Thank you ! :)

Comment: It's an often encountered issue. :)

Answer (score 11):

### z-index

Use CSS style `z-index` that sets vertical order of your elements. And give it a high enough value so it will always display on top:

```
#facebook {
    height: 249px;
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Elements are usually rendered (to simplify it and in terms of vertical ordering) according to their natural HTML flow. So later defined elements are rendered over previous ones.

Comment: For further reading visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context

Comment: @VirusZ: A very valuable read I'd suggest myself as well. thanks for providing it in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS style z-Index to show your menu on top.

```
#menu
{
z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: Just setting the z-index on a fixed element won't do the trick. Setting the absolute position won't give you the effect your after. Perhaps setting a parent to fixed position and the child to absolute position and the appropriate z-index?

An example:

```
.fixed { position: fixed; z-index: 4000000; width: 200px; right: 0; top: 0; cursor: pointer; }
.fixed .show-menu { display:block; background-color: #ffffff; width:100%; padding: 10px; font-size: 18px; right: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 60000000; }
```