# How can I add a div content area to the top of the page?

Tags: html, addition

I'm trying to add a header area to the top of a html page with a background image where I can display some content.

Here is a preview of the theme I'm editing:
http://live.bobosh.com/frontium/

I've tried adding:

```
<div class= "top">
    .top {
    width:100%; 
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url ('/img/background.png') repeat-x;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

It just pushes everything down and doesn't show my background image.

Thanks.

EDIT: Ok, I was able to just use background color and borders to get the div looking the way I wanted it and it is fixed to the top. However, it's covering up part of my header area now. I want it fixed to the top, but don't want it displaying over any of my other content. I just want it displayed above.

How could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: background.png is in your root folder img directory?

Comment: your site is quite impressive ..:)

Comment: @Thomas Spade Are you trying to put a div that always stays on top when the page is scrolled down? Then [Have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702050/fixed-position-div-always-appear-on-top)

Answer (score 0):

[look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzKKt/) i think you have no image or path is wrong in  /img/background.png

```
`background-image: url ('/img/background.png') repeat-x;`
```

remove `repeat-x` and check if u want u can add 
`background-repeat:repeat-x;` to your css

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. I've checked the image directory and path multiple times and I know it's correct. I think it has something to do with where I'm placing the div on the html page.

Comment: Yes I saw that, I even changed the path to the image you used in the example. http://www.thewwwblog.com/images/google-chrome-ball.jpg and still got nothing.

Comment: remove your repeat x from css